# Want to learn Restful API, don't know where to start

Tags: android, rest, web-services

I'm aan Android developer I'm making app with simple login and sending and receiving messages and pictures. Searching on internet making me really confuse. I don't know where to start and what to use. There are many ways to make and many libraries like node.js PHP phalcon, asp.net MVC, ruby sinatra etc. I just want to know where should I start and what should I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you mentioned Android, Java has many options for creating RESTful backends. Dropwizard is fairly straight-forward and comes with its own built-in server, which means you won't have to worry about setting that up yourself. Play is another good option. There's a bit of a learning curve with it, but once you figure it out, it has a lot of tools out of the box that help you make REST APIs.

Here's the documentation for Play:

https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaHome

P.S. - This question is likely to get flagged as not being the right fit for SO. You'll probably still get replies, but asking for opinions is something that people will try to discourage you from doing.

Comment: Really, you should start with what you know first. Stick with something in Java, since you have that experience. Branch out after that if you feel the need or want to try something different. Node and Express might be a good option for that, but for now, stick with Java.

Comment: Hey thanks for ur help. Dropwizard is good but I think it for local host. Is it possible i create free web hosting site and upload my code there like i m not talking about just dropwizard, if i use php or something else. Hope u get my point

Comment: you would be able to host the jar Dropwizard created on any of the popular web hosting providers (Digital Ocean, AWS, etc.) I think you can even get AWS free for a year to try it out. I've never deployed a Dropwizard app that way myself, but I know there are docs about deploying Java applications on the AWS website.